# C# закрыть форму из отдельного класса

Tags: c#

дорогие форумчане! 
Нажимаю Проект->Добавить класс. Добавляю класс vjuh. Создаю метод iTyPetyh
И тут меня возникает вопрос.. Как мне в этом методе закрыть форму Form1? Уже несколько часов листаю интернет, но никак не могу найти решение.

```
Applicatiob.Exit(1);
```

..и прочий код меня никак не выручает. Дело в том, что при выходе определённого if мне надо закрыть программу..
Заранее спасибо всем, кто поможет решить сию задачу!

Comment: ну так показали бы код который у вас не работает. Смотрели в отладке, `if` вообще выполняется хотя бы?

Comment: @rdorn даже без `if` не могу закрыть. Банально, при нажатии на `button1` мне надо вызвать `class.start();` которая запускает поток `thread` созданный в классе `class()`. В потоке сразу указываю `close();` А в `close()` написано `thread.Abort();` И после этого мне ещё надо закрыть `Form1`

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте минимальный пример кода для воспроизведения проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если класс знает хоть о каком-то элементе на форме, которую нужно закрыть:

   control1.FindForm().Close();
2. Если нужно просто правильно закрыть все формы - можно через Application.OpenForms

   Application.OpenForms.Cast().Reverse().ForEach(f => f.Close());

А вообще, если экземпляр класса vjuh используется на на форме, логичнее в конструктор vjuh'а передать форму и запомнить ее в виде field'а. И при выполнении некоторого его метода этот field использовать. Например так:

```
class vjuh
{
    Form _f;
    public vjuh(Form f){_f=f;}

    public void iTyPetyh(){_f.Close();}
}
```

Comment: Зачем в вашем коде `Reverse()`?

Comment: Не помогло. Выше указал в комментарии что именно мне нужно

Comment: @tym32167 чтобы формы закрывались в обратном порядке

Comment: обратном чему? Они в OpenForms отсортированные?

Comment: @tym32167 практика показывает, что OpenForms следует порядку открытия окон, и если открыто несколько модальных окон подряд, а на их закрытии заявлена какая-либо логика, логичнее будет закрывать их в обратном порядке

Comment: Я согласен с вами, просто думал, что порядок там как то зафиксирован в доках, но ничего такого не нашел.

Answer (score -1):

Если не стоит задача экономии памяти, просто скрой `form1` при переходе с помощью `hide();`.

А потом открой (создай) форму vjuh